# Hide scrollbar when its not working

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I use css overflow-y: scroll, to add custom scrollbar to my div text with a specific height. it works nice when text is longer than div height, but when text is shorter thats when I don't need to show the custom scrollbar, is there anyway to hide it?
because I apply to a tab so tab1 less text don't want to show it, tab2 a lot of text it should be showing to scroll.
I can not use overflow-y:hidden because then it not apply for all tabs and responsive mode.
here is picture: [image]

html looks something like this:

```
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="tab1">
                 <div class="tab-text"> only few text </div>
            </div>
             <div class="tab2">
                 <div class="tab-text"> 
                    a lot of text here
                    a lot of text here
                    have to scroll.....
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

css:

```
      .tab-text{      
         overflow-y: scroll !important;
         overflow-x: hidden;
         padding: 30px;
         height: 230px;
      }
      .tab-text::-webkit-scrollbar,  {
         width: 7px;
      }
      .tab-text::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
         -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
         border-radius: 10px;
         background: rgba(223,207,183,0.8);
          -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to `overflow-y` `auto`

```
.tab-text{      
         overflow-y: auto !important;
         overflow-x: hidden;
         padding: 30px;
         height: 230px;
      }
```

Comment: its very simple but I don't know it, thank you so much